# linux symlink() function broken on absolute paths

Tags: c, linux

Why does this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void) {
        const char filea[] = "../test/hunspell";
        const char fileb[] = "testa/dictionaries";
        int returnr;
        returnr = symlink(filea, fileb);
        printf("%d\n", returnr);
        return returnr;
}
```

Return 0 and i get this:

```
[gala@arch test]$ tree
.
├── symtest
├── test
├── testa
│   └── dictionaries -> ../test/hunspell
└── test.c

[gala@arch test]$ pwd
/home/gala/testing/test
```

But this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void) {
        const char filea[] = "/home/gala/testing/test/hunspell";
        const char fileb[] = "/home/gala/testing/testa/dictionaries";
        int returnr;
        returnr = symlink(filea, fileb);
        printf("%d\n", returnr);
        return returnr;
}
```

Returns -1 and fails.

Why does the c symlink() function fail on absolute paths but works on relative paths? Is there something I'm missing?

Why is it broken?

Comment: Have you checked what `-1` means?

Comment: I can't find any reference online. I can find "static" Strings that point to integers probably, but im lost where to look. I don't do C i do only Java, im doing a C library bridge to use libc and Linux functions inside Java

Comment: `man symlink`, look at the error codes and: Either find their definitions in your source tree or just dump their values.

Comment: Add a `perror("symlink");` after the failing `symlink` to see the error. Since both programs create [I presume] the same link, and all components of the full path exist (e.g. `/home/gala` exists) the second one is probably just saying "linkpath already exists". (i.e.) It was created with the first program. When testing, be sure to remove the link you wish to create first. You could either look at `errno` and ignore `EEXIST` or better yet, do an `unlink(fileb)` first above the `symlink` If you run pgm1 again, I bet you get an error

Comment: Nice! It returns > symlink: No such file or directory
But why? Why doesn't the first code example return that when creating a symlink of a file that does not exist?

Comment: It means that one of the directories in the path `/home/gala/testing/testa/` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your paths are good ? If you ran `tree` in `/home/gala/testing/test`, then the path for `fileb` should be `/home/gala/testing/test/testa/dictionaries` instead of `/home/gala/testing/testa/dictionaries`.